# easy-peasy: useStoreState not working with ES6 class instances

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class, easy-peasy

In [easy-peasy](https://easy-peasy.vercel.app/), the [`useStoreState()`](https://easy-peasy.vercel.app/docs/api/use-store-state.html) hook does not cause a re-render when we use the hook to access the store's field that stores an ES6 class instance. For example:

`store.js`

```js
import { action, createStore } from "easy-peasy";

class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

const store = createStore({
  person: new Person("Tom", "20"),  // <-- Stores ES6 class instance
  updatePersonName: action((state, payload) => {
    state.person.name = payload;
  })
});

export default store;
```

`app.jsx`:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useStoreActions, useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const person = useStoreState((state) => state.person);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{JSON.stringify(person)}</p>
      <EditPerson />
    </div>
  );
}

function EditPerson() {
  const person = useStoreState((state) => state.person);
  const updatePersonName = useStoreActions(
    (actions) => actions.updatePersonName
  );
  return (
    <input
      value={person.name}
      onChange={(e) => updatePersonName(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Easy Peasy w/ ES6 classes]

If we try to type in the input box, even though the `updatePersonName` action is successfully dispatched (see the screenshot below), the value of the input box remains unchanged. The `person` store state is not successfully updated and the `useStoreState()` hook does not cause a re-render.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason

easy-peasy uses the [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) library to convert the mutations into the equivalent immutable updates against the state. However, Immer does **not implicitly** support custom ES6 classes.

According to the [Immer's docs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/complex-objects):

> Plain objects (objects without a prototype), arrays, Maps and Sets are always drafted by Immer. Every other object must use the `immerable` symbol to mark itself as compatible with Immer

### Solution 1

We can make our custom ES6 class compatible with Immer [according to the docs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/complex-objects):

`store.js`

```js
import { action, createStore } from "easy-peasy";
import { immerable } from "immer";  //  Add this (1)

class Person {
  [immerable] = true;  //  Add this (2)

  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

const store = createStore({
  person: new Person("Tom", "20"),
  updatePersonName: action((state, payload) => {
    state.person.name = payload;
  })
});

export default store;
```

[image: Edit Easy Peasy w/ ES6 classes (Solution 1 - Immer)]

### Solution 2

Alternatively, we can convert the ES6 class into a plain JavaScript object if your ES6 class is simple enough:

`store.js`

```js
import { action, createStore } from "easy-peasy";

const store = createStore({
  // Use a plain JS object here 
  person: {
    name: "Tom",
    age: "20",
  },
  updatePersonName: action((state, payload) => {
    state.person.name = payload;
  })
});

export default store;
```

[image: Edit Easy Peasy w/ ES6 classes (Solution 2 - Plain Object)]

### Note on `easy-peasy-decorators`

According to [Easy Peasy docs](https://easy-peasy.dev/docs/community-extensions/#easy-peasy-decorators), there's a community extension called `easy-peasy-decorators` that provides the ability to generate stores via classes and decorators.

Unfortunately as at 2022 Nov, that library does **not** support Easy Peasy **v4** or above (as hinted in [this issue](https://github.com/easypeasy-community/decorators/issues/3))

### Reference

- [Easy Peasy Docs - State type restrictions](https://easy-peasy.dev/docs/tutorials/primary-api.html#state-type-restrictions)
- [easy-peasy GitHub issue #809](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/easy-peasy/issues/809)